# e.preventDefault() behvaing differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a very simple jQuery UI spinner as follows:

```
<input value="2" class="form-control ui-spinner-input" id="spinner" aria-valuemin="2" aria-valuemax="24" aria-valuenow="2" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton" type="text">
```

Using jQuery I set the above text box readonly true/false. The readonly and value is set based on the checkbox a user selects and that function looks like

```
 function checkBoxes() {
    var $targetCheckBoxes = $("#BoxFailure,#InstallationFailure");
    $targetCheckBoxes.change(function () {
        var isChecked = this.checked;
        var currentElement = this;
        var $radioButton = $('.usage-failure-type-radio');
        $targetCheckBoxes.filter(function () {
            return this.id !== currentElement.id;
        }).prop('disabled', isChecked);
        $('#spinner').val(isChecked ? this.value : '').prop('readonly', isChecked);
        $radioButton.first().prop('checked', isChecked);
        $radioButton.not(':checked').toggle(!isChecked).parent('label').toggle(!isChecked);
        $('.usage-before-failure > div > span.ui-spinner > a').toggle(!isChecked);
    });
}
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is when the `#spinner` input is readonly and if the user presses the back space I want to prevent the default behaviour e.g. do navigate away from the page. For this I thought I'd do the following:

```
$('.prevent-default').keydown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Which works fine if the input has the class `prevent-default` on page load. However, if I add it in my `checkBoxes` function in the following line

```
$('#spinner').val(isChecked ? this.value : '').prop('readonly', isChecked).toggleClass('prevent-default')
```

Then I press the backspace it ignores `e.prevenDefault();`

But if I do

```
$('#spinner').val(isChecked ? this.value : '').prop('readonly', isChecked).keydown(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Then it works absolutely fine.

Can someone tell me why this is happening please.

The reason I want to use a separate function with a class name is because I have various inputs which get set to read only based on different check/radio values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me why this is happening please

This is because of the DOM parser and the timing when JavaScript is executed.

If you already have an element with a class `prevent-default` in your DOM before JS is executed, then the JavaScript will recognise and handle it correctly. If you instead add the class afterwards with JS, then you have to re-initialise the keydown-event again to make it work.

To re-initialise you will need something like this:

```
function checkBoxes() {
    var $targetCheckBoxes = $("#BoxFailure,#InstallationFailure");
    $targetCheckBoxes.change(function () {
        ...

        $('#spinner').val(isChecked ? this.value : '').prop('readonly', isChecked).toggleClass('prevent-default');
        // assign new keydown events
        handleKeyDown();
        ...

    });
}

function handleKeyDown() {
    // release all keydown events
    $('#spinner').off( "keydown", "**" );
    $('.prevent-default').keydown(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // do more stuff...
        });
}
```

Comment: How do I go about re-initialising the keydown-event?

Comment: But wouldn't `handleKeyDown()` fire when the user unchecks the checkbox?

Comment: In this case, yes. If you need to prevent that, you have to unset the keydown-event of spinner and then assign it again. See updated answer ;-)

Comment: Is there no way of toggling this function?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't! As long as you don't want to implement a setTimout-function that runs every 10 ms, checks the DOM for changes and reacts to it accordingly :D

Comment: running a setTimeOut function would slow the page wouldnt it?

Comment: It wouldn't slow the page down, but it would be just a dirty useless workaround. nevermind!